# Fullscreen CSS Layout Challenge (Multi-column w/ Header and Footer)

Tags: css, layout, fullscreen

I've done quite a bit of research on CSS fullscreen layouts I just couldn't seem to find something like what I'm trying to do. I'm looking for a fullscreen layout with a header, footer, multiple columns, and a sidebar. Here's an ascii model and then a photoshop mockup. Anyone have any ideas? I'm yet to find a fullscreen layout technique to work.

```
+-----------------------+-------+
|                       |       |
+-------------+---------+       +
|             |         |       |
|             |         |       |
|             |         |       |
|             |         |       |
|             |         |       |
|             |         |       |
+-------------+---------+-------+
|                               |
+-------------------------------+
```

[image: Layout Prototype]

So tell me, how do you think this could be accomplished? I'm open to CSS 3 or HTML 5 options as cross-browser compatibility is a bonus, but not a necessity (WebKit is the target platform).

Comment: Is that design supposed to fill the viewport only? Or should there be a vertical scrollbar?

Comment: Ideally it would scale to the browser and each pane would scroll if necessary. I was able to come up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/TX7Zv/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the below code in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/davinciwanab/nX4eq/

```
<style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            }
        #header {
            float: left;
            width: 75%;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: #333;
            }
        #colRight {
            float: right;
            width: 25%;
            height: 500px;
            background-color: #CCC;
            }
        #content {
            float: left;
            width:  50%;
            height: 480px;
            background-color: #EEE;
            }
        #contentRight {
            float: left;
            width: 25%;
            height: 480px;
            background-color: #AAA;
            }
        #footer {
            width: 100%;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: #777;
            }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="colRight"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="contentRight"></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You came as close as possible to what I was looking for and I thank you. I was able to move forward and figure everything out. Here's what I finally came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/TX7Zv/2/ Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Glad to help!  Checked out your code, and it appears to be working just like you'd hoped (I assume).

Answer (score 1):

here is a rough wireframe

http://jsfiddle.net/samccone/UYeEr/